# How to the Get content of html page into pdf

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, pdf, thymeleaf

I am trying to get or download the content of my html page that contains a lot of information(tables..) into pdf file.
i try using this code but the got me the information as html information(with  tags).

**Q** : How to do get this content into a pdf?
here is my code :

```
try{
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Hamza Amrani/Desktop/riad/testFile1.text");
    FileWriter writer_f = new FileWriter(file);
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8090/afficher?id=3");
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
      String line;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
         writer_f.write(line);
      }
      reader.close();
      writer_f.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all your question is not clear. If you want to write a full a html page in pdf, then the code for getting html contents from **URL** is correct . But for writing this contents in a pdf file, you will need [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), a Java library which allows to create PDF, read PDF and manipulate them. You can follow this tutorials to understand about **iText** :

- [Creating PDF with Java and iText - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html)
- [iText – Read and Write PDF in Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/itext-read-and-write-pdf-in-java/)

But if you need to parse a **HTML** page like getting information inside a `<h1>` tag, you will need a **HTML Parser**. [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) is the best solution for this problem. Follow this links for better understanding about **jsoup**:

- [Jsoup Tutorial and Examples](http://howtodoinjava.com/jsoup/complete-jsoup-tutorial/)
- [jsoup Example Tutorial – Java HTML Parser](http://www.journaldev.com/7144/jsoup-example-tutorial-java-html-parser)

Hope this will solve your problem.